# Murky & Dirty gem calculation to poison enemies

Tags: bloodborne

Let us assume that I have a set of [murky (dirty) gems](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/p/blood-gems.html) in my [Blade Of Mercy](http://www.bloodborne-wiki.com/2015/03/warped-twinblades.html) which grant me a slow (fast) poison of +15 in total. I am facing an enemy with poison resistance of 120 (180).

*How many hits of the Blade Of Mercy do I need to slow (fast) poison them?*

Clearly, I am more interested in how the calculation works rather than just a number…

Note that my Blade Of Mercy are at +10. I am in NG+. However, none of this should matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have no hard evidence, it seems that around +30 or so poisoning it takes around eight or nine hits to get some poison effect. Even with top tier poison gems, you are unlikely to get any decent poison damage from the BoM.

**Using dirty gems in general (and in this case) is a waste of your time.**